# Rails remote form onkeyup for text_field_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to setup a search field that will search as the user types (I am working to transition away from using the Filterific gem since it does not support API's)
I have the form working so when the submit button is clicked it loads in with javascript instead of loading a new page.
My View:

```
<%= form_tag(search_items_path, method: 'post', remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'search_query', nil, placeholder: 'search item name', onkeyup: "$(this).parent('form').submit();" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
post "/search_items" => 'items#search_items'
```

Controller (currently only doing the filter for testing purposes)

```
  def search_items
    puts params
    @items = Item.order('display_name DESC').paginate(:page => 1)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I have had 2 different issues. The first is before I added the `:authenticity_token => true` to the form_tag whenever I typed anything it was loading another page and giving me `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):`
After fixing that now it loads a new page `http://localhost:3000/search_items` which does not work due to the controller.
Basically I can't get the onkeyup to work with the remote: true. I found several stack overflow questions on this but it seemed all of them worked with the above setup.
I am on ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.2.0
More info:
Comparing the log entry.
When clicking the submit button:

```
Started POST "/search_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-14 23:01:40 -0500
Processing by ItemsController#search_items as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DIzeHBdHOY3TWXU5JEeND65+OwvmqygXHLLfIyEwO9BxuEKL/OyhAdiwSrXiO4opt57Qp6ajJB2rxxmCGWgOvQ==", "search_query"=>"ab", "commit"=>"Search"}
```

When typing:

```
Started POST "/search_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-14 23:03:04 -0500
Processing by ItemsController#search_items as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DIzeHBdHOY3TWXU5JEeND65+OwvmqygXHLLfIyEwO9BxuEKL/OyhAdiwSrXiO4opt57Qp6ajJB2rxxmCGWgOvQ==", "search_query"=>"abc"}
```

Comment: I just plugged in something similar on a search form on my app, and it seems to work just fine.  In my example, I was doing a GET request to the index action, though.  I also switched parent('form') to closest('form') since my input had a wrapping div.  Can you please double check that you have <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in your layout?

Comment: I just double checked and that is in my layout.  
The onkeyup in my case is at doing the right form since it is going to /search_items (which is where the js is). However it is not doing a .js request.

Comment: I did also try setting the method to GET. The submit button still worked but same affect on typing anything.